# How to decrease the color depth of jpeg image to 256 colors in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bit, color-depth

```
MemoryStream msSave = new MemoryStream();
ImageCodecInfo pngCodec = ImageCodecInfo
    .GetImageEncoders()
    .Where(codec => codec.FormatID.Equals(ImageFormat.Png.Guid))
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (pngCodec != null)
{
    EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters();
    parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 256);
    img.Save(msSave, pngCodec, parameters);
}

img.Save(msSave, imageFormat);
```

I tried out this code but not giving me the correct result?

Could any one help me out.

Comment: Instead of chaining `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` you can use only `FirstOrDefault` with a predicate. Also, you probably expect only one codec to match provided GUID, so you really want `SingleOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 256);
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 8);
```

Comment: Tried again no success

Answer (score 0):

```
MemoryStream msSave = new MemoryStream();
ImageCodecInfo pngCodec = ImageCodecInfo
    .GetImageEncoders()
    .Where(codec => codec.FormatID.Equals(ImageFormat.Png.Guid))
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (pngCodec != null)
{
    EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters();
    parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 256L);
    img.Save(msSave, pngCodec, parameters);
}

img.Save(msSave, imageFormat);
```

Does this work?